# How do I add a mouseover event to an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a mouseover event that would turn my images background to black while adding text that would describe the link to another web-page. But everything that I have tried either in CSS or JavaScript does not work and I get errors, not sure how to fix the problem?

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
addEventListner("mouseover", link);
addEventListner("mouseout", linkOut);

function link() {
  one.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  one.textContent = "Our Games";
  one.style.textAlign = "center";
  one.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
}

function linkOut() {
  one.style.backgroundColor = "";
  one.textContent = "";
}
```

```css
This is my my CSS, I think that the overlay option is not working 
do to the grid that I have set up for my images. But I am 
not quit sure why it wont work.

#dragon {
 height: 200px;
}
#chaos {
 height: 600px;
}
#logo {
 height: 150px;
}
#thunder {
 height: 600px;
}
#dice {
 height: 235px;
}
h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
   padding: 32px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
}

/*--------------grid for my images--------------------------*/
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: black;
}
.row {
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 0 4px;
}
.column {
 -ms-flex: 33.33%;
 flex: 33.33%;
 max-width: 33.33%;
 padding: 0 4px;
}
.column img {
 margin-top: 8px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
}
/*--------------overlay for links--------------------------*/


.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: black;
}

.column:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
This is my HTML


<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <a id="one" href="#"><img id="chaos" src="cardchaos.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <a id="two" href="#"><img id="dragon" src="dragon card.gif" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt=""></a>
    <a id="three" href="#"><img id="dice" src="Img Try Again.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <a id="four" href="#"><img id="thunder" src="Thunder Bolt.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `HTMLElement.addEventListener` is spelt wrong - you spelt it as `addEventListner`.

Comment: And `<a>` tag displays `inline` by default so you might need to change your `<a>` tags style too.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your script. Also what you are trying to do is that you edit the element directly. If you try to remove the textcontent of the element on mouseleave you will lose the original element as well. I recommend doing this with css.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529981188441-8a2e6fe30103?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div> 

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: black;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Have a look of my example and then underneath I fixed your version what is happening. https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/pojQxNB

Comment: I am glad that you brought up the CSS. I actually tried that code for the CSS overlay first and when I couldn't get it to work I tried a JavaScript solution but it didn't work for me either. Here is my CSS that I was using, I think that the overlay isn't working do to the grid that I have set up for my images, but I couldn't find a solution to fix the CSS.

Comment: /*--------------grid for Images--------------------------*/
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: black;
}
.row {
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 0 4px;
}
.column {
 -ms-flex: 33.33%;
 flex: 33.33%;
 max-width: 33.33%;
 padding: 0 4px;
}
.column img {
 margin-top: 8px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: @CalebErickson could you please update this to your main post what you have tried and why it didn't work out? Maybe provide a codepen as well for your problem?

Comment: I updated the main post, sorry I'm a newbie. I don't have a codepen but that is on my to do list.